# What is SVN error code 200015?

Tags: svn, error-code

During an export operation using PySVN, I got an exception:

```
ClientError: ('', [('', 200015)])
```

Presumably this error code is one of those defined in [svn_error_codes.h](http://svn.collab.net/svn-doxygen/svn__error__codes_8h-source.html). But... which one? And how do I find the text description of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grepping through the sourcecode for `200015` I get

```
subversion/bindings/javahl/src/org/tigris/subversion/javahl/ErrorCodes.java:    public static final int cancelled = 200015;
subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/err.py:CANCELLED = 200015
```

This maps to this pieces of code in svn_error_codes.h:

```
#define SVN_ERR_CATEGORY_SIZE 5000
[...]
#define SVN_ERR_MISC_CATEGORY_START     (APR_OS_START_USERERR \
                                     + (16 * SVN_ERR_CATEGORY_SIZE))
[...]
SVN_ERRDEF(SVN_ERR_CANCELLED,
    SVN_ERR_MISC_CATEGORY_START + 15,
    "The operation was interrupted")
```

The value of `APR_OS_START_USERERR` seems to be defined in APR. I did not find a ready-made value, but the value should be (by calculating backwards) 120000.

Comment: That must be it then. Damn. I'm buggered if I can figure out why it's happening though, but that's another story.