# svnadmin load : interpreting error codes

Tags: svn

Is there some sort of reference to consult when `svnadmin load` throws an error?

For instance below, when I try to load a self-created dump file, I get

```
svnadmin: E160017: Attempted to set textual contents of a *non*-file node
```

What does `E160017` correspond to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

160017 is SVN_ERR_FS_NOT_FILE "Name does not refer to a filesystem file"

[svn_error_codes.h](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.7/svn__error__codes_8h_source.html) defines all the error codes, where each error category is of size 5000

```
#define SVN_ERR_CATEGORY_SIZE 5000
```

and start error code is 'APR_OS_START_USERERR', whose value when calculated comes to 120000. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964549/what-is-svn-error-code-200015))

So, calculation for error category is:

```
(error_code-120000) / 5000

(160017-120000) / 5000 = 8 (whole number) = category SVN_ERR_FS_CATEGORY_START
```

So error code 17 under this category is

```
SVN_ERRDEF(SVN_ERR_FS_NOT_FILE,
          SVN_ERR_FS_CATEGORY_START + 17,
          "Name does not refer to a filesystem file")
```